# Whether should use @Enable* again when @EnableAutoConfiguration?

Tags: spring-boot

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` will load spring.factories, then Spring will load manage Configuration classes, whose function are overlapped with @Enable*(eg: `@EnableCaching`/`@EnableWebMvc`), so Whether should I use @Enable* again when `@EnableAutoConfiguration` existing?

Comment: It's not really clear what is your question. You have `@Enable*` annotation for different cases.

Comment: Yes @Enable* is for different cases. @ENableAutoConfiguration is only configuring beans as defined https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html

Comment: If you want to disable auto config of certain features then add specific `@Enable` annotation. For instance if you add `@EnableWebMvc` Spring Boot will not auto configure webmvc for you (and you will loose some features). For other `@Enable` annotations you will need to add them as Spring will not automatically add them like `@EnableScheduling` so it basically depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hey, bro, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` will load many Configuration class in spring.factories, eg WebMvcAutoConfiguration. I think WebMvcAutoConfiguration is enough to complete mvc configuration, there is no need to use `@EnableMvc`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yeah, I am agree with you, I just find some blog where some example just use `@EnableCaching` for cache configuration, but `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is enough.